# how to use AWS instance's IP address dynamically in an ansible playbook without saving it in an external file using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, microservices

I have 2 clusters, 1 of Cassandra(4 node cluster) and other of Kafka(3 node cluster) on EC2. I have a playbook which deploys my microservices on AWS instances, for that microservice playbook i have maintained an inventory file which stores my cassandra/kafka host's IP adresses in a variable as follows:

```
cassandra_hosts = 'X.X.X.X:9042,X.X.X.X:9042,X.X.X.X:9042,X.X.X.X:9042'
kafka_host = 'X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092'
```

The microservice playbook is somewhat as follows:

```
- hosts: dynamic_hosts
  become: yes
  become_user: xxxxxx
  become_method: sudo 

  vars:
   ansible_connection: "{{ connection_type }}"
   ansible_ssh_user: "{{ ssh_user_name }}"
   ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "{{ ssh_private_key_file }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Register Service as an Upstart
      shell: chdir="{{dest_location}}" "./{{upstartscript}}.sh" " -p  {{service_port}}  -u  {{service_uri}}  -v  {{service_version}}  -c  {{cassandra_hosts}}  -k  {{kafka_host}}  -l  {{log_level}}"
      register: escript

    - name: Register Service as an Upstart Output
      debug: 
       msg : "{{ escript.stdout }}"
```

The code above is the way in which I retrieve the IP Address which i have hardcoded in the inventory file(mentioned in the first part of the code).

What I am trying to achieve is, how can I store the IP addresses of my AWS instances dynamically in my playbook and use it in my microservices playbook without storing the IP addresses in the inventory file, any suggestions

P.S. I request you to ask any question if needed, this is my first question here, Thanks in advance

Hi,
I also need to get the output of the kafka cluster, but kafka cluster outputs it in the AWS console in a different way as follows:

```
|||                                                           Outputs                                                           
|||
||+---------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------
----------------------------------------------------+||
|||        Description        |    OutputKey    |                                  
OutputValue                                  |||
||+---------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------
----------------------------------------------------+||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  ZookeeperLink  |  
X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181     
|||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  Node2DNSName   |  ip-X-X-X-
X.ec2.internal                                                 |||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  KafkaLink      |  
X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092     
|||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  Node3DNSName   |  ip-X-X-X-
X.ec2.internal                                                |||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  Node4DNSName   |  ip-X-X-X-
X.ec2.internal                                                |||
|||  IP of Primary Seed Node  |  Node1DNSName   |  ip-X-X-X-
X.ec2.internal
```

I just want to ouput the IPs of the part KafkaLink, any help on this:

```
    X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092
```

I tried the following command but it is not working:

```
 aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name IngKafkaCluster --query 'Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputValue' --output text
```

I get the following ouput on the above command , which is not wrong but not exactly what i want:

```
X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181,X.X.X.X:2181        ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal    X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092,X.X.X.X:9092        ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal   ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal   ip-X-X-X-X.ec2.internal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the AWS EC2's Ip addresses you can try the following command which will fetch the AWS output to a file you desire:

```
 aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name IngCassandraCluster --query 'Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputValue' --output text --> kunaltest.text
```

you can add this line in your playbook under :shell:" to make it do what you want.

Comment: i have edited the scope of the question can you please guide me on the kafka part?